# Detailed Flutter Deep Links explanation?

Tags: ios, flutter, deep-linking

I can't get any part of deep linking working in my Flutter app. None of the documentation I can find on this is anywhere near adequate. eg none mention this, but it appears https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode/supporting-associated-domains?language=objc that I need to provide a file on my server? Nor is there any discussion I can find of that or in what way I need to set up an associated domain.

May app on launch directs to the login page of a local copy of my website. Following login, my site redirects to myappname:mywebsite.

In my Info.plist, I have:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>CFBundleTypeRole</key>
        <string>Editor</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLName</key>
        <string>mywebsite</string>
        <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>myappname</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Following a tip from someone on reddit (as I say, this stuff isn't documented anywhere!), I added an associated domain in XCode applinks:mywebsite?mode=developer

I also redirected my domain in my local hosts file to my local machine. I've verified in the browser in the iOS simulator that the domain redirect is working in the simulator.

It appears from Apple's documentation that I should see a hit on my website to `.well-known/apple-app-site-association` but I get nothing.

My app successfully redirects on launch to the login page, but when I complete the login, my site issues a redirect to myappname://mywebsite but the browser in the simulator is just ignoring this.

I opened the console on the device browser from Safari, but nothing is reported.

Comment: I have tried with both a custom scheme and with http or https, with no different result.

Comment: Just tried on Android with the same result.